# Trying to get OAuth dialog to work

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

I am at this step in getting my app started in the documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth

In there is a code block that (supposedly) forwards the user to a request dialog asking permission to access certain bit of information about them. I've placed this code block into the PHP script that my canvas URL points to, and changed the `$app_id` and `$canvas_page` to my application ID and canvas URL respectively. Instead of getting the expected dialog, I receive this following error from facebook:

```
"An error occurred. Please try again later."
```

No other details about the error are present. I've tried some variations of the script, and have even tried loading up this URL directly just to see if that would work. Note that I've replaced `YOUR_APP_ID` and `YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE` with the appropriate values and made sure that spelling and/or punctuation are correct:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE&scope=email,read_stream
```

For the redirect URL, I've tried prepending it with `http://`, `https://`, and no prefix at all. All with the same result.

My question: **is the example in the documentation broken, or is the oauth link provided in the documentation currently down?** The vague nature of the error is somewhat frustrating since I can't tell if it's something I'm doing wrong or if it's facebook's oauth function that's at fault.

Comment: Argh! Chalk this one up to user error on my part. Instead of using the *numeric* application ID, I was using the namespace string instead. Once I used the correct value in my OAuth URL, the expected page loaded up just fine.

I wish these epiphanies occurred to me *before* I went posting on forums asking for help.

Comment: it's nice you have found a solution on your problem, but if you found a solution, you have to answer your question and select it as a correct one. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Ah I would have at the time, but the limitation on my account prevented me from doing so until several hours after I posted my original question. I will do so now. :D

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that instead of using the numeric application ID that facebook assigned for me when I originally created the app as the YOUR_APP_ID parameter in the OAuth URL, I was using the application namespace string. Facebook didn't understand this sort of request, and returned the generic error message.

Once I used the numeric app ID, the OAuth dialog popped up to ask permission to access my account, as expected.